# Variable being passed in as null - Powershell

Tags: powershell, function

So I have an issue that has been bugging me for a few hours now.

I have two functions, `Write-Log`, and `LogProfileRemoval`.   In `Write-Log`, I pass in the two arguments as shown here.

`LogProfileRemoval('$LogEventDetail', 100000)`

But when I check the variables of `LogProfileRemoval` they are shown like this

```
$LogEventDetail = '$LogEventDetail' 100000 
$LogMethod = $null
```

I am aware that I have quotes around the variable `$LogEventDetail`,  that was part of my testing to figure this out. Really that variable could be anything and it still concats those two variables into one and leaves the 2nd parameter as a null value.

What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

```
function LogProfileRemoval($LogEventDetail, $LogMethod)
{
   Switch ($LogMethod)
    {
        'EventLog' {LogToEventLog($LogEvent)}
    }
}
function Write-Log($logDetail, $logEvent=2)
{
    $LogEventDetail = New-Object EventLog -Property @{EventTimeStamp=(Get-Date);EventType=$logEvent;EventDetail=$logDetail}
    $LogMethod = 1
    LogProfileRemoval('$LogEventDetail', 100000)
}
```

Comment: Could you revisit the wording of your post for clarity? You said "In Write-Log, I pass in the two arguments as shown here." then gave an example using LogProfileRemoval. I would like to help but I'm having a hard time understanding the issue.

Comment: Do not use parenthesis when calling functions in PowerShell.  Call your function like `LogProfileRemoval -LogEventDetail $LogEventDetail -LogMethod 100000` or `LogProfileRemoval $LogEventDetail 100000` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.2#parameters

Comment: Thank you for that,  I am so used to C# that I have always done it like that,   By changing it to best practices and doing exactly what you said,  it has worked out for me.  I just have to remember that powershell is losely typed and needs to be powershell format not c# format.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

So by not following best practices, was the issue. Weird becuase I have always wrote my powershell scripts like this.  Always been a not fan of the Param way of doing it.  I changed it to best practice way (sorta) and it worked great.

I would like to know why it didn't work though but overall It just goes to show me to quick being lazy and do it the right way.

Code working shown below

```
    function LogProfileRemoval
    {
        param( 
                $LogEventDetail,
                $LogMethod
            )
    
       Switch ($LogMethod)
        {
            'EventLog' {LogToEventLog($LogEvent)}
        }
    }
    function Write-Log($logDetail,$logEvent=2)
    {
        $LogEventDetail = New-Object EventLog -Property @{EventTimeStamp=(Get-Date);EventType=$logEvent;EventDetail=$logDetail}
        $LogMethod = 1
        LogProfileRemoval -LogEventDetail $LogEventDetail -LogMethod 'EventLog'
    }
```

Comment: To explain why it doesn't work, it's because when `LogProfileRemoval('$LogEventDetail', 100000)` is called `('$LogEventDetail', 100000)` is treated as an array and passed in as a single argument to the first parameter: $LogEventDetail.  No argument is passed in for $LogMethod which is then treated as null.  It's really the comma that causes this, not the parenthesis.  `LogProfileRemoval '$LogEventDetail', 100000` will do the same thing.